# Explore the solution space of an equation?

Tags: real-analysis

Lets say I have a equation:

$x = \frac{A}{B} \times k$

and I want to know all values that satisfy the constraint where $x = 1$, and the limits of $A$, $B$ and $k$ are$-10$ to $10$. How would I go about doing this?

Note: the variables are **real** numbers

Comment: Integers, or real numbers?

Comment: should mention its real numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your equation as $B=kA$, in which $k,A,B \in [-10,10]$. Here, the only non-obvious constraint is that $\vert k \vert \cdot \vert A \vert \leq 10$.  Our solution set then looks like
$$\{(k,A,B)\}=\{(k,A,kA): \vert k \vert \leq 10,\, \vert A \vert \leq 10,\,\vert k \vert \cdot \vert A \vert \leq 10\}.$$ 
Geometrically, the boundary of admissable triples pairs $(k,A)$ looks like the union of the solution sets of  $xy=\pm 10$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A,k$ were anything. Could you choose $B$ to satisfy $x=1$? When is there no such $B$?